# Remove indentation from docbook table head

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop, docbook

I am laying out a table with column headings using DocBook and XEP.  It appears that the column headings are indented, not left justified.  The problem is that on narrow columns the indentation pushes the column heading in to the right cell margin and the rendering is all bunched up and unreadable.  Is there a way to get the column headings to be left justified within the cells on the heading row?

Here is a partial listing of the xml code:

```
<informaltable frame="all">
   <tgroup cols="4" align="left">
      <colspec colwidth="1*" />
      <colspec colwidth="1*" />
      <colspec colwidth="2*" />
      <colspec colwidth="0.7*" />
  <thead>
    <row>
      <entry>Operator</entry>
      <entry>Syntax</entry>
      <entry>Description</entry>
      <entry>Result</entry>
    </row>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
    <row>
      <entry>
        <para>Logical 'or'</para>
      </entry>
```

[Here is what the output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6iy9.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I chased it down a bit more, updated my tool chain and style sheets and problem still there.  I took a look at the customization xsl and the `thead` template was being overridden, and that is where the problem was coming from.  The customization did not include `start-indent` and `end-indent` attributes on the `<fo:table-header` element.  I added those and all is good now.  Appreciate your help.